# Prove existence of Correlated Equilibrium

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium, algorithmic-game-theory

How can I prove that every finite game has at least one Correlated Equilibrium?

I know there is the idea that it has already been shown that every finite game has a Nash equilibrium and then from there we know that every NE is also a CE.

But is there a more "straight forward" approach which takes the definition of a CE into account?

Comment: Correlated equilibrium can be written as a linear program, it is then easy to see that the linear program has at least one solution. Is that what you have in mind?

Comment: @GameTheorist1982 Thank you for your reply. Do you mind giving me a hint of the straight-forward solution?

Comment: See [Hart and Schmeidler (1989)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3689835).

Comment: @HerrK. I read the proof in the paper before and actually that's the reason why I am asking because I don't understand it.